# R system() cannot allocate memory even though the same command can be run from a terminal

Tags: r, linux

I have an issue with the R `system()` function (for running an OS command from within R) that only arises when the R session uses up more than some fraction of the available RAM (maybe ~75% in my case), even though there is plenty of RAM available (~15GB in my case) and the same OS command can be easily run at the same time from a terminal.

System info:
64GB RAM PC (local desktop PC, not cloud-based or cluster)
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
R version 3.5.2 (executed directly, not e.g. via docker)

This example demonstrates the issue. The size of the data frame `d` needs to be adjusted to be as small as possible and still provoke the error. This will depend on how much RAM you have and what else is running at the same time.

```
ross@doppio:~$ R

R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> n <- 5e8
> d <- data.frame(
+   v0 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v1 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v2 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v3 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v4 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v5 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v6 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v7 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v8 = rep_len(1.0, n),
+   v9 = rep_len(1.0, n)
+ )

> dim(d)
[1] 500000000        10

> gc()
             used    (Mb) gc trigger    (Mb)   max used    (Mb)
Ncells     260857    14.0     627920    33.6     421030    22.5
Vcells 5000537452 38151.1 6483359463 49464.2 5000559813 38151.3

> system("free -m", intern = FALSE)
Warning messages:
1: In system("free -m", intern = FALSE) :
  system call failed: Cannot allocate memory
2: In system("free -m", intern = FALSE) : error in running command
```

The call to `gc()` indicates R has allocated ~38GB out of 64 GB RAM and running `free -m` in a terminal at the same time (see below)  shows that the OS thinks there is ~16GB free.

```
ross@doppio:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64345       44277       15904         461        4162       18896
Swap:           975           1         974
ross@doppio:~$
```

So `free -m` can't be run from within R because memory cannot be allocated, but `free -m` can be run at the same time from a terminal, and you would think that 15GB would be enough to run a light-weight command like `free -m`.

If the R memory usage is below some threshold then `free -m` can be run from within R.

I guess that R is trying allocate an amount of memory for `free -m` that is more than actually needed and depends on the amount of memory already allocated. Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I've run into this one.  R runs fork to run the sub process, temporarily doubling the 35GB image to more than the 64GB you have.  If it had lived it would have next called exec and given back the duped memory.  This isn't how fork/exec is supposed to go (it is supposed to be copy on write with no extra cost- but somehow it does this in this case).

It looks like this may be known: that to fork you must have enough memory to potentially duplicate the pages (even if that does not happen).  I would guess you may not have enough swap (it seems at least the size of RAM is recommended).  Here are some instructions on configuring swap (it is for ec2, but covers the use of Linux): https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-memory-swap-file/

Comment: Good answer. Allow me to add that the (helpful) `free -m` shown displays a rather surprisingly low amount of swap. "These days" (ie for probably a decade+ if not longer) you can add swap space in a running session pointing to a swapfile (rather than swap partition and reboot).  You could try that to enlarge the virtual memory.  But John is spot on: "3x" is still the rule of thumb.

Comment: @john-mount increasing the swap size fixed the issue. By executing `sudo swapon /swapfile` and `sudo swapoff /swapfile` (for a sufficiently large swapfile) in a terminal window, I could make `system("ls") succeed or fail in an R session.

Comment: @dirk-eddelbuettel 1GB swap partition is the default installing Ubuntu 18.04 with LVM and LUKS full disk encryption. With 64GB RAM, if I *need* to swap I have a problem and more swap space just delays discovery of the problem. I don't want a significant fraction of my primary SSD allocated to a file that is never used. I argue against "3x" for large-RAM PCs. My mainboard has space for 128GB RAM, and an unused 384GB swap file doesn't sound like a good use of primary SSD space.

Comment: "Is the default" where? At AWS?  I am typing this at at 18.10 box which surely has more than 1gb swap.  But your previous reply directed to @john does what I suggested to you: use a temp swap file if need be to avoid processes from being killed.

Comment: The default advice for AWS (but they come configured with zero swap).  I think Dell laptops also come configured with swap==RAM.  But yes, there are good reason to not waste flash-drive on swap.

Comment: @dirk-eddelbuettel my "1GB swap is the default" was wrt installing from the official Ubuntu 18.04 iso image to a desktop PC with an LVM and LUKS file system. At the time I thought 1GB seemed very low, so did some searching and found a range of views. Given the large amount of RAM on the PC and my intended use pattern I was convinced by the "minimal swap" position. This current cannot-allocate-memory issue is the only problem that has arisen for me as a consequence. Going forward I will try to avoid forking from a large process and use temporarily increasing the swap as a fallback method.

Comment: Odd. It's been a year since I did a fresh install. And I used a different scheme of `/boot`, `swap` and a single large partition (on a raid mirror) as I had realized over the years that lvm is nice ... but that I effectively never resize and eventually hit the barriers. Anyway -- "way back when" installations used to default to swap partitions suggesting "two times total ram".  It may be more complicated now that we have oodles of ram -- the main point is that 1gb is plain silly.  Too little to matter.  Might be worth following up on the Ubuntu side.  And glad it's working now :)

Comment: Yes - I must look at it again next time I fresh install. I never resize my file system either, so probably don't need lvm (unless it is required for luks). I may end up opting  for zero swap on my large RAM machine. I have a more sensible swap size on my 8GB RAM laptop. There it mostly serves as a warning mechanism for when I open too many tabs in FireFox.

Comment: Beside the discussion of how much swap to allocate, I think this specific behavior in R is new and deserves some attention. Following an upgrade to R-3.6 I meet it all the time. It affects all system() commands, making it impossible to e.g. install packages when one uses more than half of the memory. Does anyone know if this indeed is a new R behavior, and perhaps why it has been changed? (On my work server running R-3.5.0 this problem does not occur. i.e. I can fill up my memory as instructed in the question and run simple system("ls") like commands.)

Comment: I can add the following: On my ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine this problem was first encountered when upgrading to R 3.6 from R 3.4. Un-installing R 3.6 and re-installing R 3.4 did not resolve. On my other dt running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and R 3.2, the behaviour is not observed, i.e R seems not to allocate memory equivalent to its current workspace upon running a simple system() command.